# white patches on bald head

Tags: hair

I decided to go bald since I was losing hair anyway, but i did not expect the white patches.

Any idea what can be done to get rid of it?

I have heard of applying lemon for half an hour and rinsing it with and some over the counter psorasis shampoo, is that enough?[image]

Comment: Hi RAN, Welcome to Lifehacks… Consider going to a healthcare professional to have your head examined before trusting wacky medical advice from complete strangers. It could be as simple as Vitiligo - or as complex as cutaneous T cell lymphoma - I'm voting to close the question.